# When should I create another field as Primary Key?

Tags: mysql, performance, primary-key

I'm developing a home automation system using MySQL. I have some arduinos connected through ethernet shields and a Raspberry Pi that manages them using a MQTT server. This server handles the communication between all the devices (each arduino is only connected to the raspberry, which processes the request and sends another request to the same or another arduino).

Also, each arduino is identified by its MAC address.

I have an input (for reading switches and sensors) and an output (turning on and off lamps) system using the arduinos. Each value is stored in the input and output tables.

**device**

```
 - id : CHAR(12) PK NOT NULL // The MAC Address
 - type : VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL // I also manage a door lock system
```

**input**

```
 - device : CHAR(12) NOT NULL // FK from device table
 - selection : TINYINT NOT NULL // Selects input port
 - value : INT // Stores the input value
```

The output table is very similar. Both tables have other fields not important to my question.

When someone presses a switch a message is sent to the server, the server processes the request, updates the database and sends back other messages to other arduinos according to a set of tables that manages triggers.

I started noticing some delay turning on the lamp and after some code dump I found out that the majority of the time is spent on the database query.

Is it better if instead of using the MAC address as the PK I create another field (INT AUTO_INCREMENT)? What engine is fastest os better for this situation?

*PS: The server runs a long running PHP script (it was the best language I knew at the time I started developing this and I was using the web UI as a reference. I know that Python may be better for this case).*

Comment: Adding tables reduces query speed. There are valid use cases for "denormalization" (i.e. having repeating data in one table). You could denormalize, i.e. move everything to one table and seeing how it affects your speed. Not something to be taken lightly but maybe your disk is highly fragmented or super slow for some reason. But for small tables I have a hard time believing this is your bottleneck. If the query really is your bottleneck, maybe create a map object in memory so you can avoid disk access entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the difference between `CHAR(12)` and some size of `INT` cannot explain a performance problem.  Sure, a 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED` would probably be better, but not worth it for such a 'small' project.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the queries, plus `EXPLAIN SELECT` for any slow queries.

The `PRIMARY KEY` is accessed via a BTree (see Wikipedia); it is very efficient, regardless of the size of the table, and regardless of the size of the column(s) in the PK.

Here's one reason why I insist on seeing the schema.  If, for example, the `CHAR` is a different `CHARACTER SET` or different `COLLATION` on a pair of tables, the `JOIN` between the tables would not be able to use the index, thereby slowing down the query by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

From [Primary Key Tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-primary-key/)

> Because MySQL works faster with integers, the data type of the primary
>   key column should be the integer e.g., INT, BIGINT.You can choose a
>   smaller integer type: TINYINT, SMALLINT, etc. However, you should make
>   sure that the range of values of the integer type for the primary key
>   is sufficient for storing all possible rows that the table may have.

Without seeing you full schema for the entire database, it would be hard to give you a bunch of recommendations. But in my experience, I always like to just let my PK be an autoincrement integer. I would then make my MAC address an index (possibly unique) to make joining efficient.

Comment: I mean you are using a 12 CHAR as your PK which MySQL always has to check for uniqueness.